# <tr> and <td> tags overwriting <pre>

Tags: php, html, html-table, pre

Is there a reason why `<tr>` and `<td>` tags would work whilst inside a `<pre>` tag?

I am using a `<pre>` tag to show some PHP code on a website and within the code are various instances of the html tags `<tr>` and `<td>`, these are jumping out of the `<pre>` tags and executing at the bottom. Why would they do this??

They are included after `echo` and inside "" and '' and both are executing the same. I have no `pre` in my CSS and can't find any similar problems on the net.

Example:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo "<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td><td>E</td></tr>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $info['a'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['b'] . "</td>"; 
echo "<td>" . $info['c'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['d'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $info['e'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
};
echo "</table>";
```

I have tried using `print`, no change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to encode the `<` and `>` as HTML entities.

https://mothereff.in/html-entities

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references

so `<` would be `&lt;` and `>` would be `&gt;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the specific use of `<pre>` tag is to display the element as what is it, even non-`&nbsp;` multiple spaces will be display, nor a breakline by a keyboard *(non-`<br />` tag)*, and not to fail a HTML tag. You can use this format `&lt;tag>` to fail a tag. But I didn't know if `<pre>` can fails a PHP code.